# Pinter's Abstract Algebra, Chapter 25 Exercise B3.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Let $F$ be a field.  Explain why the following is true in $F[x]$:
>   Any two distinct irreducible polynomials are relatively prime.

Is there a typo in this question?

A counter example: Suppose $F$ is $\mathbb{Q}$. Consider polynomials $x+1$ and $2x+2$.

1. Both are *irreducible*, for they cannot be expressed as a product of two non-constant polynomials.
2. They are *distinct*, for $x+1\ne 2x+2$.
3. They have a common factor $(x+1)$, and therefore *not relatively prime*.

Hence there exists two distinct irreducible polynomials that are *not* relatively prime.

Comment: Probably he meant to restrict to *monic* irreducibles (or say "nonassociate" vs. "distinct")